# Add class ONLY to the elements in viewport

Tags: jquery

**The problem**

Id' like to fade in content only when it comes into viewport. [A solution I found here works fine](https://www.superhi.com/blog/how-to-add-web-design-elements-that-fade-in-and-out-on-scroll) as long as I apply the code to sections. But I want to fade in single items—here represented by p tags. What I get is that all p tags are faded in at once. From what I understood, the code adds the class at once instead of one by one.

**My approach so far**

1. Tested the code with sections. Works fine.
2. Re-worked the code to fade in p tags. Works fine but fades in ALL items at once.
3. Cursed at my computer. A lot.

**The code**

```js
  $(document).scroll(function() {
  var pageTop = $(document).scrollTop();
  var pageBottom = pageTop + $(window).height();
  var items = $('.wd-icons');

  for (var i = 0; i < pageBottom; i++) {
    var item = items[i];

    if($(item).position().top < pageBottom) {
      $(item).addClass('wd-visible');
    }
  }
})
```

Please find here a [codepen](https://codepen.io/eishle/pen/VwLBooa) for demonstration purpose.

So, what's my mistake?

Comment: Take a look at https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/